# SQL Server 2008 replace multiple word to single word

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, str-replace

In SQL server 2008 , I need to replace many 'Pass' word into single 'Pass'

'Pass Pass Pass Pass Pass'  Replace into  'Pass'

in here 'Pass Pass Pass Pass Pass' can be change.
Ex :

```
'Pass '                      =>  'Pass'
'Pass Pass '                 =>  'Pass'
'Pass Pass Pass '            = > 'Pass'
'Pass Pass Pass Pass Pass'   =>   'Pass'
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Share more info. Are they separated by single space or possible multiple whitespaces? The easiest way is to use multiple `REPLACE`

Comment: it is possible multiple whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in a single column and 'PASS' is all you expect in that column then you could do something like:-

```
case 
  when YourColumn LIKE '%PASS%' then 'PASS'
  else YourColumn
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a query to replace {2 spaces} with {1 space}" " and run it repeatedly until {2 spaces} is not found any more.
2. Write a query to replace PASS PASS with PASS and run it repeatedly until PASS PASS is not found any more.

Comment: What with tabs/new line and so on? Also show on actual query.